# Values are not inserted properly in the SQLite database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I'm setting SQLite to my app signup page and I want to use my mobile number instead of email for signing up. My app shows no error but the toast ("Registered Successfully") never appears and activity `mainWindow` never starts.

My Database file is below

```
public class DatabaseHelp extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DatabaseHelp( Context context) {
        super(context,"Login.db",null,1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("Create table user(First_NAME text ,Last_NAME text,mobile number primary key ,password text)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists user");
    }

    //inserting in database
    public boolean insert(String First_NAME,String Last_NAME,String mobile,String password){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("Fisrt Name",First_NAME);
        contentValues.put("Last Name",Last_NAME);
        contentValues.put("Mobile Number",mobile);
        contentValues.put("Password",password);

        long ins=db.insert("user",null,contentValues);
        if(ins==-1) {return  false;}
        else{ return true;}
    }

    // if number exists
    public Boolean chkemail(String mobile){
       SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("Select * from user where mobile=?",new String[]{mobile});
        if(cursor.getCount()>0) return false;
        else return true;
    }
}
```

My Signup page java file is below

```
public class signup extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelp db;
    EditText e1,e2,e3,e4,e5;
    Button b1;
    public void onClick(View view){
        Intent i1 = new Intent(this, forgotpass2.class);
        startActivity(i1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        db=new DatabaseHelp(this);
        e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        e3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        e4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        e5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText8);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String s1=e1.getText().toString();
                String s2=e2.getText().toString();
                String s3=e3.getText().toString();
                String s4=e4.getText().toString();
                String s5=e5.getText().toString();
                if(s1.equals("")||s2.equals("")||s3.equals("")||s4.equals("")||s5.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    if(s4.equals(s5)){
                        Boolean chkemail=db.chkemail(s3);

                        if(chkemail == true) {
                            Boolean insert = db.insert(s1,s2,s3,s4);
                            if(insert == true) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registered Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Mobile Number already exits",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Passwords do not match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What should I do to make the code work properly?

Comment: Did you try to debug it by stepping through in a debugger and seeing where things didn't happen as expected?

Comment: I can tell you one definite problem is you can't have column names with spaces in them.

Comment: At the beginning you say *My app shows no error* and now *the error is as follows*. Also the error is about a Spannable string but the code you posted has nothing of it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things in your code which need to be pointed out. First, about the `insert` function, the column names have spaces and I think you should get rid of those spaces for SQLite column names. Modify your `insert` function like the following.

```
public boolean insert(String First_NAME,String Last_NAME,String mobile,String password){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("first_name",First_NAME);
    contentValues.put("last_name",Last_NAME);
    contentValues.put("mobile",mobile);
    contentValues.put("password",password);
    long ins=db.insert("user",null,contentValues);

    if(ins==-1) return  false;
    else return true;
}
```

Now, once you are done with this, I think your `chkemail` function now works correctly. Because, previously the field `mobile` was not found in the database table as the column name was different (i.e. the column name in your code was `Mobile Number`, which I have changed in the `insert` function to match with the query).

```
public boolean chkemail(String mobile){
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from user where mobile=?",new String[]{mobile});

    if(cursor.getCount()>0) return false;
    else return true;
}
```

Please note that I have changed the return type of the `chkemail` function from `Boolean` to `boolean`.

And finally, in the `signup` activity, you need to modify the part mentioned below as well.

```
// Changed from Boolean to boolean
boolean insert = db.insert(s1,s2,s3,s4);

if(insert == true) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registered Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // Start the new activity here
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, mainWindow.class);
    startActivity(newIntent);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: still the same problem is occurring with the error i have edited in post

Comment: Same problem occurring.